# Active Directory Certificate Services CEP/CES won't show templates added to CA

Tags: ad-certificate-services, pki

I am running this on Server 2016, domain is 2012r2, client computers are Win10 and Win7.

I have a two-tier PKI infrastructure (offline root) that I recently set up, and I have had no issues with most of the configuration. The issue that I currently have is in regards to the CEP/CES web services.

The intermediate CA is segmented from most of our domain-joined computers, so I cannot use the LDAP enrollment policy to enroll (RPC access to the CA from most of the clients will not be allowed).  With that in mind, I created 3rd server where the CRL/AIA information resides, as well as hosting the CEP/CES web services (Kerberos, no key-based renewal).  Domain-joined machines can add and validate the enrollment policy server with no problem, but ***when I try to request a new certificate, the list of templates available is blank***. The certificate enrollment dialog shows the message "Certifcate types are not available"

When I use the LDAP-based enrollment policy on those domain-joined computers that have access to the intermediate CA, I see all the templates that I have setup the CA to issue, and can submit enrollment requests for any of them with no problems.

When I configured the CEP web services, I had to intially change the policy ID for the web services as outlined [here in section 3c (GUID conflicts with existing GUID when LDAP and CEP...)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7734.certificate-enrollment-web-services-in-active-directory-certificate-services.aspx#Error_Messages) in order for the clients to validate the enrollment policy server correctly.

I have verified that my test machines, and test users all have read and enroll privileges on all the templates I am expecting to see, I have restarted both the CA and the server hosting the CEP/CES web services.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to re-add the enrollment policy on client after GUID change?

Comment: Yes, In fact, it wasn't until I changed the GUID that I could successfully add the enrollment policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally caved and paid for a support incident with Microsoft.  They had me uninstall and reinstall the web services, and everything worked like a miracle.
We never found the underlying cause.

Comment: I can't believe I finally found someone with exactly the same issues as me and this is the answer.

Thank you for taking to time to add it though, +1

Comment: No problem.  I am glad it helped you out.  I know it was a PITA for me for a very long time.